# Why libraries automatically added?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I created a project in Visual Studio 2019. (Create a project > Windows Desktop Wizard > Console Application with all options unchecked.)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcsc4.png)

Something like this code is working but I didn't add math.h library to the code. I don't understand why sqrt function is working without error.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << sqrt(9);
}
```

Comment: Some headers may include other headers, even if the standard does not require it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have the following files:

```
a.h
b.h
main.cpp
```

In main you have :

```
#include <a.h>

int main() {
   // Use func from a.h
   aFunc();
   // Use func from b.h
   bFunc();
}
```

Like your situation, let's say this builds no problem. How does the program know what `bFunc` is then?

The likely answer is that `a.h` looks like this :

```
#include <b.h>
aFunc();
```

That means that when you include `a.h` you are also including `b.h` from within.

Now if you are using `b.h` functions specifically it's considered good practice to also include `b.h` in main. If include guards are setup then there should be no problem and it'll be easier to read through the code.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if some other `#include` includes the missing header, but you should not depend on this. For instance, this code does not compile in gcc or in clang.

But even if it compiles **now**, it might not compile without including the missing header in a future version of the same compiler. I actually had this problem recently where I was using `std::runtime_error` in a file without including 
`<stdexcept>`. It worked for years and then when Arch updated gcc to version 10 it stopped compiling and I had to add the missing include.